# Where is the ID3v2 documentation?

Tags: metadata, mp3, id3, id3v2

I'm looking for the ID3v2 documentation/norm. The official site id3.org seems to be unreachable. Is this specification still used ? (I'm wondering this because of the "downness" of the official website)

Comment: Yes, the specification is still used and valid. You can always use the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/*/www.id3.org)

Answer (score 5):

The availability of *any* website is unbound to the use of *any* specification, because even if one or both of it become outdated all files that used it until that date won't disappear magically at that date - software still needs to expect old files that have been crafted when "old" specifications were in use.

As said in the comment: if you ever come across a dead link (and that is the case for quite a couple specs/manuals then search for exactly that URI in https://archive.org/ or one could even try Wikipedia: i.e. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3 already explains v1.x completely.

This is a complete list of what to expect in MP3 files. The informal ones mostly rely on official ID3v1 or ID3v1.1 tags, but not always. ID3v2 can also be used in other files (i.e. AIFF, WAV, ASF, MP4). APE is intended for files APE, MPC, WV but not bound to - it can also appear in MP3:

| what | purpose/summary | original | archived |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID3v1 and ID3v1.1 | at end of file | https://id3.org/ID3v1 http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/mpeghdr.htm#MPEGTAG | [2021-07-07](https://web.archive.org/web/20210707175853/https://id3.org/ID3v1) [2023-10-25](https://web.archive.org/web/20231025231323/http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/mpeghdr.htm#MPEGTAG) |
| ID3v1.2 (informal) | extending ID3v1 length | http://www.birdcagesoft.com/ID3v12.txt | [2023-10-03](https://web.archive.org/web/20231003025920/http://www.birdcagesoft.com/ID3v12.txt) |
| ID3v2.2 | at front of file | https://id3.org/id3v2-00 | [2021-07-06](https://web.archive.org/web/20210706095505/http://id3.org/id3v2-00) |
| ID3v2.3 | 4 letter frame IDs | https://id3.org/id3v2.3.0 | [2021-02-04](https://web.archive.org/web/20210204135457/https://id3.org/id3v2.3.0) |
| ID3v2.4 | UTF-8 support | https://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-structure https://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-frames https://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-changes | [2021-07-06](https://web.archive.org/web/20210706041518/https://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-structure) [2021-03-29](https://web.archive.org/web/20210329042828/https://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-frames) [2021-07-11](https://web.archive.org/web/20210711160915/https://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-changes) |
| ID3v2.3 and ID3v2.4 addendums | more frames | https://id3.org/id3v2-chapters-1.0 https://id3.org/id3v2-accessibility-1.0 | [2021-07-06](https://web.archive.org/web/20210706042952/http://id3.org/id3v2-chapters-1.0) [2021-08-12](https://web.archive.org/web/20210812061112/https://id3.org/id3v2-accessibility-1.0) |
| Lyrics3 (informal) | song texts | https://id3.org/Lyrics3 | [2021-10-25](https://web.archive.org/web/20211025162400/https://id3.org/Lyrics3) |
| Lyrics3v2 (informal) | linking cover | https://id3.org/Lyrics3v2 | [2021-10-25](https://web.archive.org/web/20211025162402/https://id3.org/Lyrics3v2) |
| Enhanced TAG (informal) | speed rating | http://www.fortunecity.com/underworld/sonic/3/id3tag.html | [2012-03-10](https://web.archive.org/web/20120310015458/http://www.fortunecity.com/underworld/sonic/3/id3tag.html) |
| APEv1 | at end of file, before ID3v1 | https://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=APEv1_specification | [2023-07-02](https://web.archive.org/web/20230702133814/https://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=APEv1_specification) |
| APEv2 | can be at file start | https://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=APEv2_specification | [2023-07-02](https://web.archive.org/web/20230702133807/https://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=APEv2_specification) |