# ID3 Parser and Editor

Tags: parsing, mp3, id3, id3v2

I'm writing an ID3 parser and editor. It does already support ID3v1, v2.1-2.3. Are there any other widely used ID3 versions or extensions? For example, I've read about Enhanced ID3v1 tag (which goes before ID3v1) and starts with "TAG+", but I've never seen it inside MP3 files. Should I implement support for it anyway?

Comment: I'd definitely also support ID3v2.4, it's already in use and supports UTF-8 text encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- "ID3v2.1" never existed.
- Yes, **Enhanced TAG** identifies by `TAG+`, which extends **IDv1**.
- For a list of all metadata systems to be expected in MP3 files see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62366354 - top priority should have **ID3v2.4** as you will encounter those most aside from **ID3v2.3**. Then go for informal and/or legacy ones because those can still be encountered (just because files become old doesn't mean they cease to exist).

Keep the following things in mind when parsing files:

- A file can have **both**: IDv1 and IDv2 tags.
- A file can have **multiple IDv2 tags** (i.e. IDv2.3 and IDv2.4). Although it shouldn't occur it should pose no problem to your parser to also accept multiple tags of the same version.
- ID3v2 is not limited to **MP3 files** (but IDv1 and all its informal extensions are).
- Consider the following parsing order in an MP3 file:

  1. Check for **ID3v1** at the end of the file.
  2. Check for **ID3v1.2** in front of ID3v1.
  3. Check for **Enhanced TAG** in front of ID3v1.
  4. Check for multiple **ID3v2** at the start of file and, as for ID3v2.4, a footer at the end of the file in front of all ID3v1-like tags.